# Reliable way to create scheduler for executing Java program in Windows

Tags: java, windows, scheduled-tasks

I have a task in which, I have monitor a folder for new files and upload its content to database. For this, I have written a Java Program, created an executable JAR and scheduled it for execution after fix interval i.e after 5 min. using Windows Task Scheduler on Windows 7.

I have to ask about reliability of this approach. How reliable is Task Scheduler? Is there any better approach like creating a windows service ,etc by which I can schedule my Program/ JAR.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Best Regards,
Kunal

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/)

Quartz Scheduler is a Java-based open-source job scheduling service which is used in most of the applications to schedule their timely jobs.

Comment: Thanks Ashok, How will I handle the scenario when my machine reboots?

Comment: You have to use Some queuing techniques to handle it. When your server starts you should trigger the jobs that where on the queue. Try Redis Queuing or ActiveMQ or use database to store those information and trigger it on the server startup.